Verbally declaring a hand at showdown….?
2 players are in the hand at the river.  Both players check.  Player B, acting last says to Player A, “I have top pair, if it’s good, just muck your hand”
Player A, does in fact slide his cards face down toward the dealer.
Player B then also slides his cards in face down without ever showing any of the cards.
The dealer then tells Player B that he must show his cards since he verbally declared the value of his hand.
Does Player B really have to show his hand?
Is Player A ever entitled to the pot if it’s to be found that Player B has misrepresented his hand?

Cash game typically no, it can depend for cash, tournament typically yes.
Cash games you might find some card clubs/casinos will enforce a showdown ruling to claim a pot, not standard. Now if someone requests to see the hand they have the right to do so, i.e. Player A could say I want to see it. In general even if Player A asked to see and Player B had nothing Player A has already mucked so Player B would still win. Player B likely will receive a verbal warning from the dealer or floor staff about angle shooting, Player A will likely also be informed it's their duty to protect their cards.
Some tournaments are now allowing winners to not show cards if the other player mucks at showdown, like in the above situation, but the majority of tournaments still have a hand at showdown to claim pot rule.
Cards talk, when in doubt just show the cards!
